# C multiple keywords for return type in function definition

Tags: c

I am looking over some C code but can't for the life of me figure out what to google to figure out what the following extra identifier is in the following function definition:

```
//  Whats this? It seems there are two return types?
//    |
//    V 
   XN_C_API XnStatus xnInit(XnContext** ppContext) {
       ...
   }
```

I apologize if this is too far removed from its original context (its from OpenNI and I would be more than happy to post up a link if need be)

Comment: i think its some type of compiler instruction or namespace, i am not 100% sure

Comment: It must be some type of preprocessor declaration specific to OpenNI. C does **not** have multiple return types. The above is similar to `const int foo()`.

Comment: Yes I am well aware of that.  I have just never seen pre compiler guards before a function declaration like that before.

Comment: If you're using gcc, run the code through `gcc -E` to see how it looks after preprocessing; that should show you what the macro `XN_C_API` expands to.

Comment: Thank you. That may come in handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a symbol defined using `#define`. Search through the code to find where it's defined. The actual return type of your function is `XnStatus`, while `XN_C_API` is likely defined to be a set of modifier. These are typically used to define exported symbols or other attributes for functions that have the particular attribute.

For example, in my code (a DLL project on Windows), I have this:

```
#ifdef MGR_EXPORTS
    #define MGR_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define MGR_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

...

#define MGRAPI StatusCode __declspec(nothrow) WINAPI
```

All the public (exported) function declarations look like this:

```
MGR_API MGRAPI MgrInit ()
```

The first symbol `MGR_API` is used to control how symbols are exported from the DLL; the other, `MGRAPI` helps declare all public functions with the same set of modifiers and the same return type (which is `StatusCode`).

If there's ever a need to update the declaration of all public functions in this project it's easy because only the defined symbols need to be changed and all functions take the change right away.

Comment: When you say modifier, is it modifying the return type in some way or the actual function definition?

Comment: @zanegray modifiers mostly modify how the compiler compiles a function. This can be compiler-dependent; in the my example, `__declspec(nothrow)` is a Microsoft-specific modifier that tells the compiler that the function doesn't throw any exceptions, don't generate any exception-handling code. `WINAPI` is another modifier; it's usually defined as `__stdcall` for the calling convention.

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail!

Answer (score 3):

Is defined like this

```
#define XN_C_API   XN_C_API_IMPORT
#define XN_C_API_IMPORT XN_API_IMPORT
#define XN_API_IMPORT   __declspec(dllimport)
```

`__declspec(dllimport)` means that the function is imported from a DLL file.

Comment: Thank you! I just found that as well.. just had to look a bit harder :)